# how to change url if it doesnt connect to server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my doInBackground on AsyncTask i have a code to check the URL in try and catch, if the connection to server cut off, i want to change the URL the backup one.

here's my code :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://"+IPADDR+"/"+NMSERVER+"/loginNIKUUID.inc.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder;
                builder = new Uri.Builder();
                //builder.appendQueryParameter("imei", params[0]);
                builder.appendQueryParameter("nik", params[0]);
                builder.appendQueryParameter("uuid", params[1]);
                builder.appendQueryParameter("password", params[2]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
```

i want to change the url to something like this :

```
 url = new URL("http://"+IPADDR2+"/"+NMSERVER2+"/loginNIKUUID.inc.php");
```

how can i achieve that ? thanks in advance

Comment: you have already added Timeout in the try block, if the timeout occurs, it will be caught in the catch block, add another catch block for that specific Exception & change the url & do the connection again.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection#setConnectTimeout(int))

> **setConnectTimeout**
>
> ```
> public void setConnectTimeout (int timeout)
> ```
>
> Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when
> opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this
> URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be
> established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of
> zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

**Solution**

When the client cannot connect to the server within the timeout, then the app will throw a `SocketTimeoutException`, so we can use this behavior to switch to the backup server.

```
String mainUrl = "http://" + IPADDR + "/" + NMSERVER + "/loginNIKUUID.inc.php";
String backupUrl = "http://" + IPADDR2 + "/" + NMSERVER2 + "/loginNIKUUID.inc.php";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return connect(mainUrl, params);
}

private String connect(String hostUrl, String...params) {
    try {
        // Enter URL address where your php file resides
        url = new URL(hostUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "exception";
    }

    try {
        // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Append parameters to URL
        Uri.Builder builder;
        builder = new Uri.Builder();
        //builder.appendQueryParameter("imei", params[0]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("nik", params[0]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("uuid", params[1]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("password", params[2]);
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        // Open connection for sending data
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        // There is a problem with the main server, switch to backup server
        if (hostUrl.equals(mainUrl)) {
            return connect(backupUrl, params);
        }

        return "exception";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "exception";
    }

    return "success";
}
```